# Access IIS on Win10 VM

Tags: networking, windows-10, iis, vmware-fusion

I'm attempting to access a website running on IIS (Windows 10, running on a VM in Fusion).

VM is set to use NAT with a static IP defined in dhcpd.conf for the network.

Windows firewall is currently disabled, until I get this working.

I can ping the VM from the host OS (MacOS Sierra) by IP.

The website is accessible in the guest OS (Win10, IIS) via localhost and IP.

But, I cannot browse to the website (on guest Win10) from Safari (on host MacOS).

I've played with various bindings in IIS.  They all seem to work locally (in the guest OS), but nothing external.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh, the problem was Symantec.  It was running it's own firewall, in addition to the Windows 10 firewall. Thanks for the suggestions, they eventually led me to the solution.

Solution was disabling the second firewall that Symantec was running (alongside Windows Firewall).  Windows Firewall was configured to allow web traffic; Symantec was locked down tight.

Comment: So what *is* the solution? You answer do not really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of NAT, try using VMWare Fusion's Bridged Network Adapter. Other devices on the network, including the Mac itself, will see the exposed services on the Mac's IP.  Ensure that you're not running port 80 (or whichever port your IIS uses) on the Mac itself.  https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022264

Comment: I gave that a try, though the same problem persists.  Makes me think it's actually an IIS or win10 firewall problem.  The firewall should be turned off, but I wonder if there's something else preventing the connection?

Comment: Does the Mac itself have firewall enabled?  What about Antivirus / Security on either platform?  Try pinging as well, to see if the Mac vs Windows VM are reachable at all.  Also, do a sanity check to confirm that no other machine has snaffled up that IP address from the DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping the VM IP from the host OS, networking is working correctly, so what it comes down to is tweaking IIS settings.

Most likely scenario is IIS is listening only on localhost.

Try binding IIS to your local IP address instead of localhost, also check your VM's firewall settings.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, in addition to switching the network adapter to bridged. Same problem persists. Any other ideas?